# IIS 404 error on file that exists

Tags: iis, http-status-code-404

I use IIS 8 on windows server 2012 R2 .
when I Browse pages on IIS, some of them was shown, and some of them has occurred to 404 error:

> The resource cannot be found.
>     Description: HTTP 404. The resource
>   you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been
>   removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please
>   review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.

I know that pages are exist and the name is correct.
I have this site on another computer too, that works well and open all pages correctly, but in this computer some pages have the above error. both computer have the same role and features on IIS .
what should I do ?

Comment: Do the files and folders that don't work have the same permissions on them as the ones that do?

Comment: Nanhydrin thanks  to reply, yes the permissions are the same

Comment: OK, and are you seeing differing behaviour on the same file types in the same folders? Or are the files you can see different types to the ones you can't? What file types are they?

Comment: Yes, I see different behavior on the same file types in the same folders. the file types are .aspx and the same.

Comment: Since the files exist and it's not a fundamental problem with serving .aspx pages, the next possibility is what's mentioned in the error message, that a dependency of the page isn't available. Are there any errors in the machine's event viewer?

Comment: Nanhydrin, I will check it , thanks

Comment: have u found the solution?

Comment: me too facing same situation.